# Allowing SSH connection to Android Devices with Droidwall installed

Tags: ssh, firewall, connectify

I've installed SSHDroid and Droidwall on my Android device. I know that SSHDroid won't work if Droidwall is enabled. Is there's anyway to list SSH connection in Droidwall whitelist? So, I can connect to my Android device via SSH.

Comment: I would try using AFWall+ instead of Droidwall, since AFWall+ is a fork of Droidwall and Droidwall is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, but how about the settings that I have to do to allow SSH connection?

Comment: Port 22 should be accessible from outside

Answer (score 0):

```
>> AFWall+ 
>> Filter for " (root) - Applications running as root 
>> Enable LAN
```

This can work with default Port# 22